# Roboguice with different shared preferences names

Tags: android, roboguice

I am using RoboGuice in my application, and i've grown a custom to creating multiple shared preferences files so that each file plays its own role, and contains only small number of keys

however, ever since i started using RoboGuice, it injects my sharedPreferences objects with a single default file.

Is it possible to somehow direct roboguice into creating multiple files ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't use RoboGuice forever, but back in a days this was the way:

https://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/ProvidedInjections#Shared_Preferences

Comment: I don't understand how this solves my multiple files issue
I have an object named prefs
usually i would write something like this : prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("userPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

or prefs = context.getSharedPrefereneces("defaultAppPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
now if i inject the instance with 
@Inject SharedPreferences prefs;
i get an instance of the file mypackagename_preferences.xml, and i want several different files,so that other libraries i may use, that use the same file name (god knows why), don't overwrite any values i may have the same as the other libraries

Comment: I thought the link will give you an idea of how to specify the name of the SharedPreferences you're about to inject? Isn't that what you essentially need?

Comment: It shows how to specify, but i do not understand that "how do i make it multiple files", according to what i understood from this link, i can put a different name to the default file, but how do imake it several files :( ?